# how to read resources file by key?

Tags: .net, vb.net, localization, visual-studio-2017

**How do i retrieve a value from a resources file based on the key?**

I've got a resources file called `GlobalStrings.resx`:

[image]

I would like to be able to pass in `Sheepsmilk` and get back `Sheep's milk`

**How do i retrieve a value from a resources file based on the key?**

I've attempted like so:

```
Dim milk = My.Resources.GlobalStrings["Sheepsmilk"]
```

however, i'm getting the following exception:

> 'GlobalStrings' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ResourceManager`

```
Dim result = My.Resources.Resource1.ResourceManager.GetString("String1")
```

Comment: thank you very much, i've asked a follow up to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022530/how-to-change-the-language-cultureinfo