# how to change the language / cultureinfo?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, localization, visual-studio-2017

**How do I switch which resource file gets utilized based on current language?**

I've got english and a czech resource/resx files:

[image]

I can get values out of this file by doing:

```
Dim mySetting = My.Resources.GlobalStrings.ResourceManager.GetString(value)
```

When I do this, it automatically uses `GlobalStrings.resx`.

**How do I switch the language and force it to grab settings from `GlobalStrings.cs-CZ.resx?`**

Please note that this is a WinForms application.

Comment: [How to make multi language app in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990088/3110834)

Comment: This may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ckwb4b(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2